# How can my plugin use Craft's native dragdrop support

Tags: plugin-development, control-panel, ajax, garnish, modal

I am using a generic Garnish modal from Craft like so:

```
$container = $('.upload-modal');

$modal = new Garnish.Modal($container, {
    autoShow: false
});
```

I would like to have craft's native drag&drop support in this modal, i tried something like this

```
$dragDrop = new Garnish.DragDrop({
    dropTargets: ['.upload-modal__drop']
});
```

Can someone point me in the right direction. I tried to find some answers here:

https://github.com/pixelandtonic/garnishjs/blob/master/src/classes/DragDrop.js

Eventually what i am trying to achieve here, is a basic modal without any link to existing assets or so, for uploading a file with dragdrop and file select functionality. This file when processed by the plugin needs te be deleted afterwards.